# How to make directory at Linux root directory from terminal when in sub-directory?

Tags: linux, terminal, debian

Background: OS is Debian GNU/Linux.

I am trying to make a directory at root, when I am in a sub-directory.  In other words, let's say I am at the directory /a/b/c, and I want to make a directory at the root level, called d.  How do I go about doing that?

In case you can't tell, I also don't know all the right wording/terms.

**UPDATE**: I did not understand difference between **home** directory and **root** directory.  I learned about `pwd` command, and that solved the problem.  What I actually wanted was to make a directory within the home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the required permissions, you could do `mkdir /d`.

Comment: When I go to a random directory, and type: `sudo mkdir /testfolder` it requests a password but does not create that folder in my root.  @focorner what am I doing wrong?  I type `cd` after and it's not there.

Comment: I think since its at root, it might require `sudo` or something similar.

Comment: So I updated the question, but basically I was misunderstanding home vs root.  Use of `sudo` was working, but I was looking at my home directory, not my root directory.  The directories were being made, but in root, not home.  So `sudo mkdir /testfolder` would have been correct, had I been trying to make a root directory.  To make a home directory, `mkdir /path/to/home/testfolder` is the correct answer.

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer For your information, the tilde (i.e. `~`) is a convenient way of referencing the current user's home directory in a path. For instance, you could do `mkdir ~/testfolder` to create a directory named `testfolder` in the current user's home.

Comment: That is a great tip @focorner!   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It should be like sudo mkdir /name_of_directory